# Increase Disk Space on Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, containers, virtualbox, diskspace, toolbox

I'm trying to start some very large Containers on Docker Toolbox (about 18 GB in total). Unfortunately, I always get the error that there is not enough disk space. I have a 1TB HDD and there are more than 200 GB free.

How can I increase the disk space for docker toolbox?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

OK, I finally found the solution:

Open Docker Quickstart Terminal, remove the virtual docker-machine and add a new one:

```
 $ docker-machine rm default
 $ docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "100000" default
```

Comment: How can i increase the memory of docker-machine ?

Comment: Proceed with caution, this method erases all the data in volumes

Comment: units of disk-size are MB, so this will create 100 GB image, FYI

Answer (score 15):

You can resize without having to delete the VM and recreate it. By default Docker Machine uses VirtualBox, which has the `vboxmanage` command line tool for working with VMs. You can use the [modifymedium](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi) command to change disk size:

```
vboxmanage modifymedium docker-vm.vdi --resize 100000
```

Comment: This only increases "physical" space, not partition size as seen by os. Besides, for default virtualbox, the default disk is not .vdi but .vmdk which is not expandable.

Comment: He asked for increasing disk, not partition. so answer is valid, while ".vdi" also implies it just works with .vdi, and how I remember, virtualbox default type is indeed vdi, not vmdk.

Comment: The problem I had with this was dockers linux fdisking in cylinders instead of sectors. `fdisk -u /dev/sda1` solves this as per man pages https://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk

if you wish to convert .vmdk to .vdi just use `vboxmanage clonehd --format VDI disk.vmdk disk.vdi`

In the end I wound up just removing the partition and starting over. Bash history allows me to re-run the same commands as on the small 10-20GB docker toolbox ships with

Answer (score 11):

I encountered the same issue. I was not prepared to lose any of my existing images or containers, so neither creating a new disk nor pruning my data were options for me. Here is how you can resize your disk without losing any of your data.

Docker Toolbox creates a VMDK file per default. VirtualBox cannot resize this format. So, before you can resize it, you have to convert it to a VDI file.

Go to your VirtualBox interface and detach the VMDK file from your "default" machine. Afterwards, clone the VMDK file to a VDI file:

```
VBoxManage clonemedium disk --format VDI "C:\Users\me\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk" "C:\Users\me\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vdi"
```

You can now resize the VDI file. The last parameter of the following command specifies the new size in MB:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\Users\me\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vdi" --resize 30720
```

Now the disk is resized, but the partition is not. To resize the partition to fit the size of the disk, download [GParted](https://gparted.org/download.php) and create a new virtual machine. Attach your VDI disk and the GParted Live CD to the new machine. It will boot GParted and you can then use it to resize the partition to use the entire disk. There are a lot of detailed instructions how to do this on the internet, for example [here](http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/). Once you have done that, shutdown the GParted VM.

Attach the VDI file to your "default" machine. Run `docker-machine start` and it should boot your Docker machine with the resized virtual disk. If everything is working as intended, you can now delete the old VMDK file or archive it for backup purposes.

Comment: You don't need to create a second VM. You can just change CD in the existing one from boot2docker to gparted, resize the partition and change it back again.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I had a lot of stopped containers, images and volumes - eating up space. Below commands help:

`docker container prune`

`docker volume prune`

`docker image prune`

Comment: Especially useful if you have an existing vm and the virtual disk can not be resized!

Comment: "docker system prune -af" for short (-af -- Remove all unused images not just dangling ones, do not prompt for confirmation)